# Only able to run DinD containers in detached mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to setup a docker container that runs docker as a jenkins slave.

```
docker run -d --privileged jenkinsdockerdockerslave
```

When I try to kick it off like this

```
docker run -ti --privileged jenkinsdockerdockerslave
```

Here are the errors:

```
ERRO[0000] There are no more loopback devices available. 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: loopback mounting failed
```

The CMD from the Dockerfile is CMD[/jenkins-slave-start.sh]

Why would one work but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I when with [DooD](https://github.com/axltxl/docker-jenkins-dood) Docker outside of Docker